# Gridfs Metadata Not Indexed With Mongo-Connector and Elastic2_doc_manager

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, indexing, metadata, gridfs

I'm using the last version of Mongo-Connector and elastic2-doc-manager to index data stored on a Mongo DB instance with ElasticSearch 5.6.9 but i can't properly! 
All of my data are indexed except metadata stored for gridfs files. 
Following my configuration file for mongo-connector:

```
{
"__comment__": "Configuration options starting with '__' are disabled",
"__comment__": "To enable them, remove the preceding '__'",

"mainAddress": "x.x.x.31:27017",
"oplogFile": "/var/log/mongo-connector/oplog.timestamp",
"noDump": false,
"batchSize": -1,
"verbosity": 0,
"continueOnError": false,

"logging": {
    "type": "file",
    "filename": "/var/log/mongo-connector/mongo-connector.log",
    "__format": "%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] %(name)s:%(lineno)d - %(message)s",
    "__rotationWhen": "D",
    "__rotationInterval": 1,
    "__rotationBackups": 10,

    "__type": "syslog",
    "__host": "localhost:514"
},

"authentication": {
    "__adminUsername": "username",
    "__password": "password",
    "__passwordFile": "mongo-connector.pwd"
},

"__comment__": "For more information about SSL with MongoDB, please see http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/configure-ssl-clients/",
"__ssl": {
    "__sslCertfile": "Path to certificate to identify the local connection against MongoDB",
    "__sslKeyfile": "Path to the private key for sslCertfile. Not necessary if already included in sslCertfile.",
    "__sslCACerts": "Path to concatenated set of certificate authority certificates to validate the other side of the connection",
    "__sslCertificatePolicy": "Policy for validating SSL certificates provided from the other end of the connection. Possible values are 'required' (require and validate certificates), 'optional' (validate but don't require a certificate), and 'ignored' (ignore certificates)."
},

"__fields": ["field1", "field2", "field3"],

"namespaces": {
   "*.files": false,
   "*.chunks":false,
   "testDicom.immaginidicom": {"gridfs": true},
   "testDicom.refertidicom": {"gridfs": true}

},

"docManagers": [
    {
        "docManager": "elastic2_doc_manager",
        "targetURL": "x.x.x.40:9200",
        "__bulkSize": 1,
        "__uniqueKey": "_id",
        "__autoCommitInterval": 3
    }
]
```

}

Can anyone help me?

Best Regards.
Salvatore